# C# : Array of structs? Is it Possible?

Tags: c#

I cannot compile it, I have problem with array of `struct`. Is it possible to define it at struct or what?

```
struct MojaStruktura
    {
        public int CeoBroj1;
        public int CeoBroj2;
        string[] str = new string[5]; // here is the problem that I'd like to solve
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MojaStruktura m = new MojaStruktura();
            Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(m));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you have or what is the error message you get?

Comment: The CLR does not support this kind of initialization since it requires executing code.  The C# compiler normally solves it by moving the code into the constructor.  Problem is, a struct cannot have a parameterless constructor.  Gives you a good reason to make it a class instead of a struct.  Or a property with a lazy getter.  Or a factory method.  Using a class in pinvoke code is fine, it needs a [StructLayout] attribute and no ref/out in the [DllImport] declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all information are exist on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#field-initializers)

*...the default value of a struct consists of the value that results from setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null. For this reason, a struct does not permit instance field declarations to include variable initializers. This restriction applies only to instance fields...*